# Using JQuery code in RSelenium

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

Question: Is it possible to use commands of JQuery in RSelenium?

I try to use a JQuery command in RSelenium:

```
er <- remDr$executeScript('$('li.info-item div.body h3.name a[href*="infor"]');')
```

but I stack in this error:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in "er <-  remDr$executeScript('$('li.infor"
```

Comment: try executing the same command in R natively and see what you get?

Comment: @MaxPD I tried this `command<- "$(\"li.info-item div.body h3.name a[href*=\"contacts\"]\")"` but I get `$(\"li.info-item div.body h3.name a[href*=\"contacts\"]\")` I tried to make the query not to stack in quotation marks..